# Issue installing pytorch in python3.7

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, python-3.7, torchvision

Any help on how to install torch on python3.7 would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried installing torch from source code.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-version-1-10-now-available/72048

goto section Build from Source( Though it says python3.6 you can check with python 3.7 and python3.8)

Once torch is installed, install  torchvision from source

```
    git clone https://github.com/pytorch/vision
    cd vision
```

change the version you want to install and run the setup

```
    sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the issue: error: ‘vst1q_f32_x2’ was not declared in this scope

While cloning the pytorch make sure you write the branch name properly,
cloning using the below command results in the above error.

```
git clone --recursive --branch 1.6.0 http://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git
```

Use  --branch v1.6.0 instead to clone correctly.

```
git clone --recursive --branch v1.6.0 http://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git
```

Reference: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-version-1-10-now-available/72048/470